# RingCT code usage in other projects

Tags: ringct, aeon

Aside from [AEON](https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/releases/tag/v0.9.7.1) are there any other coins that have made efforts to integrate RingCT?

Are there any reports of RingCT interest for privacy use cases other than currency (smart contracts, etc) outside of the Monero project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the only other coin with working RingCT at this time is Lubecoin, a joke (I assume) coin forked off Monero very recently. I don't know where it is, but the forker was on IRC asking various questions about Monero for this.

Answer (score 2):

Particl is testing RingCT atm but it's on Bitcoin codebase. https://steemit.com/particl/@schmitzer/particl-is-testing-confidential-transactions-and-ringct-on-bitcoin-codebase